# How to deal with "avax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" when less secure app feature is not available

Tags: java, email, authentication, smtp

I'm trying to send an email using java.
This is my code.
All my credentials are correct but still I get this error.
I have seen many solutions which says turn on **less secure apps** but that feature is now disabled by google.
so how do I solve it.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "sender@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "receiver@gmail.com";

        // Assuming you are sending email from through gmails smtp
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        // Get the Session object.// and pass username and password
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("receiver@gmail.com", "password");

            }

        });

        // Used to debug SMTP issues
        session.setDebug(true);

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("This is actual message");

            System.out.println("sending...");
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the error I'm getting.
[my error in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhtZH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `less secure app` feature is removed we have to follow these below steps to use `Gmail` via `third party software` that is `App password`

Step 1: setup 2-Step Verification:- Google Account -> Security -> 2-Step Verification -> Input password as asked -> Turn ON (you could use SMS to get Gmail code to activate 2-Step Verification)

Step 2:  Generate app secret:-   Google Account -> Security -> App password -> Input password as asked -> Select the app and device... -> e.g. Other(Java application) -> Input app name e.g. MyApp -> Generate

Step 3: Use generated app secret:-  Copy a 16-character password
Use a 16-character password (instead of actual password) with Gmail username in your application

This should save your day